# Security layer issue

Tags: ssl, rds, mstsc

I have a collection of two RDS virtual servers `RDS01` & `RDS02` under Windows Server 2008 R2 and one RDS/REMOTEAPP virtual server `APP01` under Windows Server 2012 R2.

- `RDS01` & `RDS02` has the same configuration
- `RDS01` & `RDS02` can ping `APP01`

  - `ping APP01.domain.local` OK
- `RDS01` & `RDS02` can establish a connection to `APP01` via 443 or 3389 port

  - `telnet APP01.domain.local 443` OK
  - `telnet APP01.domain.local 3389` OK
- `RDS01` can connect to `APP01` via HTTPS/RDS

  - `https://APP01.domain.local/rdweb` OK
  - `mstsc` > `APP01.domain.local` OK
- `RDS02` **cannot connect** to `APP01` via HTTPS/RDS

  - `https://APP01.domain.local/rdweb` **TIMEOUT**
  - `mstsc` > `APP01.domain.local` **TIMEOUT**

I suspect a security layer negotiation issue but I have no idea how to solve this problem.

- In Internet Explorer, TLS 1.0 / 1.1 / 1.2 protocols are enabled in Internet Settings.
- In MSTSC application, prompt for credentials opens and after validate, a connection progress bar run infinitely and display: Securing remote connection

[image]

Any help will be welcome

**Edit 1**: An interesting article about this issue:

https://blog.jonschneider.com/2016/08/fix-ssl-handshaking-error-in-windows.html

Comment: Do you have all current system updates installed? (especially on the 2008 servers).

Comment: Yes I have, client and server side.

Comment: anything about errors in the event logs of both machines?

Comment: I finally found the problem : https://serverfault.com/questions/934525/ssl-tls-handshake-failure