# SSL/TLS handshake failure

Tags: windows, ssl, schannel

### Configuration

- A Windows 2008R2 RDS server `RDS01`
- A Windows 2008R2 RDS server `RDS02`
- A Windows 2012R2 RemoteApp server `APP01`

---

### Problem

Calling URL `https://APP01.domain.local/rdweb` :

- From `RDS01` : [Schannel error 40](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2012/10/05/ssltls-alert-protocol-the-alert-codes/) (handshake_failure)

[image: Fatal error handshake]

- From `RDS02` : Response code 200, cert chain OK

[image: Successful handshake]

---

### Diagnose

Using [ssldiagnos.exe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ssldiagnos/) from `RDS01` (handshake failure removed):

```
-= SUMMARY =-
Weak:         0
Intermediate: 0
Strong:       0
```

`APP01` accepts 0 SSL handshake configurations

Using [ssldiagnos.exe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ssldiagnos/) from `RDS02` (handshake failure removed):

```
[+] Testing STRONG: TLS 1, ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256 bits) ... CONNECT_OK SEND_OK RECEIVE_OK CERT_OK
[+] Testing STRONG: TLS 1, DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256 bits) ... CONNECT_OK SEND_OK RECEIVE_OK CERT_OK
[+] Testing STRONG: TLS 1, ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA (128 bits) ... CONNECT_OK SEND_OK RECEIVE_OK CERT_OK
[+] Testing STRONG: TLS 1, DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA (128 bits) ... CONNECT_OK SEND_OK RECEIVE_OK CERT_OK
[+] Testing STRONG: TLS 1.1, ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256 bits) ... CONNECT_OK SEND_OK RECEIVE_OK CERT_OK
[+] Testing STRONG: TLS 1.1, DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256 bits) ... CONNECT_OK SEND_OK RECEIVE_OK CERT_OK
[+] Testing STRONG: TLS 1.1, ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA (128 bits) ... CONNECT_OK SEND_OK RECEIVE_OK CERT_OK
[+] Testing STRONG: TLS 1.2, ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 (256 bits) ... CONNECT_OK SEND_OK RECEIVE_OK CERT_OK
[+] Testing STRONG: TLS 1.2, ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256 bits) ... CONNECT_OK SEND_OK RECEIVE_OK CERT_OK
[+] Testing STRONG: TLS 1.2, DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256 bits) ... CONNECT_OK SEND_OK RECEIVE_OK CERT_OK
[+] Testing STRONG: TLS 1.2, DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256 bits) ... CONNECT_OK SEND_OK RECEIVE_OK CERT_OK
[+] Testing STRONG: TLS 1.2, ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 (128 bits) ... CONNECT_OK SEND_OK RECEIVE_OK CERT_OK
[+] Testing STRONG: TLS 1.2, ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA (128 bits) ... CONNECT_OK SEND_OK RECEIVE_OK CERT_OK
[+] Testing STRONG: TLS 1.2, DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128 bits) ... CONNECT_OK SEND_OK RECEIVE_OK CERT_OK
[+] Testing STRONG: TLS 1.2, DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA (128 bits) ... CONNECT_OK SEND_OK RECEIVE_OK CERT_OK

-= SUMMARY =-
Weak:         0
Intermediate: 0
Strong:       15
```

`APP01` accepts 15 SSL handshake configurations

---

### Schannel

- `RDS01` SSL options activation
  [image: SSL options activation]
- `RDS02` SSL options activation
  [image: SSL options activation]

---

### Help

Any help to solve this issue will be welcome

---

### Edit 1

Here, the `RDS01` SCHANNEL registry hive export after enabling all (except SSL 2.0) manually with IIS Crypto to explicitly declare them as enabled

```
{schannel}=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL

[{schannel}]
"EventLogging"=dword:00000001

[{schannel}\Ciphers]

[{schannel}\Ciphers\AES 128/128]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

[{schannel}\Ciphers\AES 256/256]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

[{schannel}\Ciphers\DES 56/56]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

[{schannel}\Ciphers\NULL]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

[{schannel}\Ciphers\RC2 128/128]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

[{schannel}\Ciphers\RC2 40/128]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

[{schannel}\Ciphers\RC2 56/128]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

[{schannel}\Ciphers\RC4 128/128]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

[{schannel}\Ciphers\RC4 40/128]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

[{schannel}\Ciphers\RC4 56/128]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

[{schannel}\Ciphers\RC4 64/128]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

[{schannel}\Ciphers\Triple DES 168]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

[{schannel}\CipherSuites]

[{schannel}\Hashes]

[{schannel}\Hashes\MD5]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

[{schannel}\Hashes\SHA]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

[{schannel}\Hashes\SHA256]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

[{schannel}\Hashes\SHA384]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

[{schannel}\Hashes\SHA512]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

[{schannel}\KeyExchangeAlgorithms]

[{schannel}\KeyExchangeAlgorithms\Diffie-Hellman]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

[{schannel}\KeyExchangeAlgorithms\ECDH]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

[{schannel}\KeyExchangeAlgorithms\PKCS]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff

[{schannel}\Protocols]

[{schannel}\Protocols\Multi-Protocol Unified Hello]

[{schannel}\Protocols\Multi-Protocol Unified Hello\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[{schannel}\Protocols\Multi-Protocol Unified Hello\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[{schannel}\Protocols\PCT 1.0]

[{schannel}\Protocols\PCT 1.0\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[{schannel}\Protocols\PCT 1.0\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[{schannel}\Protocols\SSL 2.0]

[{schannel}\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
"Enabled"=dword:00000000

[{schannel}\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

[{schannel}\Protocols\SSL 3.0]

[{schannel}\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[{schannel}\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[{schannel}\Protocols\TLS 1.0]

[{schannel}\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[{schannel}\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[{schannel}\Protocols\TLS 1.1]

[{schannel}\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[{schannel}\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[{schannel}\Protocols\TLS 1.2]

[{schannel}\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[{schannel}\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: Is a Windows update installed patch set the same at RDS01 and RDS02?

Comment: Yes it is, `RDS01` and `RDS02` are on the same update level

Comment: Changes in schannel do not apply until the whole system is rebooted. Have you tried that? Alos, is ciphersuites branch empty on both machines?

Answer (score 2):

I've been bitten by setting the client side channels in a non backwards compatible fashion in the past. You probably should look at the client side protocols on RDS01.

In your situation I'd use IIS Crypto to enable *all* client side protocols on RDS01 (temporarily) by checking all the boxes, and using the "set client side protocol" settings, then apply best practices without the "set client side protocol".

That should rule out any client side config issues.

EDIT:

If that doesn't work I'd suggest using Wireshark to capture and dissect the handshakes and see exactly what cryptographic suites are being presented by RDS01. Personally I'd run it on APP01 so I could compare a good handshake to bad easily.

Comment: ISS Crypto screenshots was the simplest way I found to show all client side protocols are activated but that was a bad idea because it shows server side activation. Anyway, I manually activated all protocols/ciphers/hashes/key exchanges excepting SSL 2.0 to explicitly declare their activation in registry, and I restarted `RDS01` server but no change...

Comment: `Edit 1` shows the state of `SCHANNEL` registry hive

Answer (score 1):

Debugging with WireShark gave me a lot of TCP fragmentation and retransmission. After adjusting router [MSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_segment_size) setting, SSL handshakes are correctly established.

My apologies for incomplete question, the `RDS01` and `RDS02` servers are on the same network linked to `APP01` network via an IPSec VPN gateway. Since `RDS02` was working, I did not consider this possibility.

To solve my problem, I used this table and found MMS = 1384

```
  1500   Standard MTU
-   20   IP Header
-   24   GRE Encaps.
-   52   IPSec Encaps.
-  (8)   PPPoE (optional)
-   20   TCP Header
-------
= 1384   MMS
```

Open router admin page and set the new MTU or MSS